# How to return local pdf file to browser to save or open using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know how can i prompt user to download pdf file.

I have below code but it is not returning anything.

```
public ActionResult DownloadAssetClassGuide()
{
    string folder = @"C:\NewFolder";
    string file = "xyz.pdf";

    string fullPath = Path.Combine(folder, file);

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);

    return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf", file);
}
```

am i missing something?

Comment: You need to specify the `Content-Disposition` header. For more information see the post I marked this as a duplicate of.

Comment: How are you sending the user to the action method?

Answer (score 0):

Any path to a file or a folder should first got mapped to the server because you are using a virtual path. Try to map the path to the server first using 
`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(fullPath));
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
byte[] fileBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)fInfo.Length);
```

This method worked with me when I face same issue